# How can I disable the startup penguins and boot text on Linaro Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, embedded-linux, linaro

I am trying to implement a kiosk style boot on a Chipsee panel computer, running a Linaro Ubuntu variant.

I want to turn off the four penguins that show up, then the usual long list of boot messages.

Grub is not present, the boot loader is U-Boot.  I don't want to recompile the kernel if I don't have to.

I have already tried modifying linux.config in /boot, adding quiet and loglevel=3 to the kernel command line.  No change in behavior.

```
Distributor  ID: Linaro
Description: Linaro 12.11
Release:     12.11
Codename:    precise
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: you should have an SDK of your board. Search in it of any *.png file or any image file and you should find those penguins. Now you have 2 choises: 1 replace that png o bmp with your image and recompile uboot, or search the occurrance of that file name in the code and handle it. In both cases you have to recompile uboot.

Comment: Yikes.  Definitely don't want to be doing that in this situation.  Can the text output during boot be turned off without recompilation?

Comment: I sincerly think no sir. But recompiling is not that difficult.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332198/centos-remove-penguin-logo-at-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those penguins are most likely being displayed by the Linux kernel, not U-Boot.  Try adding this to your kernel command line in U-boot (bootargs)

```
logo.nologo
```

That should disable the penguins.  For the technically inclined, what that actually does is pass the module parameter "nologo" to the "logo" module (device driver.)

You will have to modify the U-Boot environment to add that string to bootargs.  If you're not familiar with U-Boot and it's environment, that might be somewhat involved depending on the U-Boot configuration, but it's all scripts and variables, so anyone with bash knowledge should be able to parse through it.  Figure out where bootargs is being set, and modify it.  The U-Boot variable 'bootcmd' is the command that gets automatically executed on powerup to boot Linux.  Follow that flow of execution, figure out where bootargs is being set, and add that string "logo.nologo" to bootargs.

Good luck!